# In my project i have one feature to read book . The book is in pdf format. I have to integrate one feature like dark mode , means,

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, background-color

I have one requirement in my project to enable dark mode for pdf view in swift4.

I am giving a brief description to understand the actual problem. In my project, I have one feature to read a book. The book is in PDF format. I have to integrate one feature like dark mode, which means on an action of a button click I have to change the PDF background color from white to black and pdf text color from black to white.
Bt I can't find any solution in pdf kit predefined functions, and also `.backGroundColor` is not able to this change.
Please provide the solution regarding this issue.

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the text and background color with Apple's PDFKit framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472810/changing-the-text-and-background-color-with-apples-pdfkit-framework)